# How to access Amazon s3 private bucket object through Zend_Service_Amazon_S3

Tags: amazon-s3, service, zend-framework

I have created a bucket on Amazon S3 and I kept some images in this bucket inside a folder. All the images are private and I am using Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 class of Zend.

How can I access the private images?

Comment: Are you trying to dowload the image file content into a php variable or do you want to generate one-time access tokens that the images can be accessed with?

Comment: Hi,I want to access it and display it on a webpage.

Comment: Through your code, i.e. your script gets the binary content from the image and then echos the image content to the browser, if so where's the benefit of using amazon as a storage in difference to your own server. Or through some sort of access token, if so have you considered that clients might be caching the html but not the images and might find your page broken some time later as the image urls are no longer valid?

Comment: Ok, but can you send me a code how to access private objects and display it using Zend_Service_Amazon_S3 class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this task by making private url  Like this

```
public function get_s3_signed_url($bucket, $resource, $AWS_S3_KEY, $AWS_s3_secret_key, $expire_seconds) {
     $expires = time()+$expire_seconds;
     // S3 Signed URL creation
     $string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n{$expires}\n/".str_replace(".s3.amazonAWS.com","", $bucket)."/$resource";
     $signature = urlencode(base64_encode((hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), $AWS_s3_secret_key, TRUE))));

     $authentication_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWS_S3_KEY;
     $authentication_params.= "&Expires={$expires}";
     $authentication_params.= "&Signature={$signature}";
     return $link = "http://s3.amazonAWS.com/{$bucket}/{$resource}?{$authentication_params}";
}
```

now use this url to get access.

Comment: what is resource in above function

Comment: That's deprecated. Use the official SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
It will return the binary data for the file stored on the Amazon S3 Bucket.

```
require_once 'Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php';
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($my_aws_key, $my_aws_secret_key);
echo $s3->getObject("my-own-bucket/myobject");
```

Documentation is here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.service.amazon.s3.html
This is example #1