# Accessing private s3 bucket files

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading files from php to s3 bucket.its uploading successfully but when i retrieve image i get following error

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<Expires>2006-03-09T07:25:20Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2016-11-05T04:38:24Z</ServerTime>
```

if i set public when uploading files then i can retrieve it but i wanted to protect from unauthorized users.

upload file code

```
try{
    $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
    $filePath = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($val), 'private');

    } catch (Aws\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n"+$e;
    }
```

Before asking question i have refereed many websites but it didnt helped me

[Amazon S3 see private files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008841/amazon-s3-see-private-files)

[PHP Amazon S3 access private files through URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749203/php-amazon-s3-access-private-files-through-url)

[How to access Amazon s3 private bucket object through Zend_Service_Amazon_S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799842/how-to-access-amazon-s3-private-bucket-object-through-zend-service-amazon-s3)

Third link is working for me but

1.is it secure to pass access key in url ?

2.is possible to view that file to authenticated user ?

```
public function get_s3_signed_url($bucket, $resource, $AWS_S3_KEY, $AWS_s3_secret_key, $expire_seconds) {
     $expires = time()+$expire_seconds;
     // S3 Signed URL creation
     $string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n{$expires}\n/".str_replace(".s3.amazonAWS.com","", $bucket)."/$resource";
     $signature = urlencode(base64_encode((hash_hmac("sha1", utf8_encode($string_to_sign), $AWS_s3_secret_key, TRUE))));

     $authentication_params = "AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWS_S3_KEY;
     $authentication_params.= "&Expires={$expires}";
     $authentication_params.= "&Signature={$signature}";
     return $link = "http://s3.amazonAWS.com/{$bucket}/{$resource}?{$authentication_params}";
}
```

Comment: So, are you saying that the upload works fine, but you are unable to access the object afterwards? What credentials are you using to access the uploaded object? Do they have permission to read objects from the bucket? Oh, and yes, it is perfectly okay to use a pre-signed URL -- even though it shows the Access Key, this is acceptable public knowledge because the Signature is generated based on the Secret Key and a hash algorithm.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein.using get_s3_signed_url method i can access files but problem is i access key is visible to public and before expire url un authenticated users can see that image or file.As you said access key is okay.what about authenticated user

Comment: @JohnRotenstein.Thanks for the info.now i have only issue with the authenticated user

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "issue with the authenticated user". Feel free to start a new Question if it requires more information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein.Think that i have website user login and upload there personal documents .That document only accessible to that user .right now in my method if they know signed url then any one can check  for example browser history.so is there any method to authenticate user to view docuemnts

Comment: It would be the responsibility of your application to verify whether a user is entitled to access a document. If so, then provide a pre-signed URL that grants access for a limited time. This should be done whenever a list of documents is displayed (with associated links). Therefore, an old pre-signed URL will no longer grant access because it expires after, maybe, 5-10 minutes.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein.Thanks ya i am doing same think what you said

Answer (score 2):

Here get_s3_signed_url function returns the url which has access key and it is not recommended. Make a function where it gets the private object object from the bucket and creates a file/an image locally in the server. Use the path of newly created image and delete the image once you are done with it.

Code in Zend:

```
require_once('Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php');

$awsKey = 'your-key';
$awsSecretKey = 'your-secret-key';

$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($awsKey, $awsSecretKey);

$bucketName = 'your-bucket-name';
$objectName = $bucketName . '/image.jpg'; //image path

$info = $s3->getInfo($objectName);

if (is_array($info)) {
    header('Content-type: ' . $info['type']);
    header('Content-length: ' . $info['size']);

    file_put_contents('image.jpg', file_get_contents($s3->getObject($objectName)));

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"image.jpg\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile('image.jpg');
    unlink('image.jpg');
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
}
```

Code in core php:

```
require_once('S3.php');

$awsKey = 'your-key';
$awsSecretKey = 'your-secret-key';

$s3 = new S3($awsKey, $awsSecretKey);

$bucketName = 'your-bucket-name';


** To store/download one image at a time**

$objectName = "image.jpg"; //s3 image path
$tempFile = "image.jpg"; //temporary/local image path

$s3->getObject($bucketName, $objectName, $tempFile); //stores the image 

if (filesize($tempFile)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $tempFile . "\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tempFile));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($tempFile); //downloads the image
    unlink($tempFile); //deletes the image from local 
}

**To store/download 'n' images at a time**

$s3ImagesFolder = 'all_images/'; //folder where all the images are 

$bucketContents = $s3->getBucket($bucketName);

foreach ($bucketContents as $file) {

if ((strpos($file['name'], $s3ImagesFolder) > -1)) {
    $tempFile = end(explode("/", $file['name']));
    $s3->getObject($bucketName, $file['name'], $tempFile); // to store 

    //to download
    if ($file['size']) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $tempFile . "\"");
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $file['size']);
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($tempFile); //downloads the image
        unlink($tempFile); //deletes the image from local 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Murthy.Thanks.can you provide the coding part

Comment: @Murthy.i am using core php not zend framework.anyway thanks if you have core php code then share and at a time i am retreiving 200+ images friom s3 bucket.Thanks