# Zend Framework 2 - Centralize media file loading from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zend-framework2

I am migrating an existing `ZF2` project from root server architecture to the cloud.

One of my tasks is the loading of media files from **AWS S3**.

I wonder what's the best approach for this. I googled around a bit and found [some](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zendservice.amazon.s3.html) [interesting](https://www.design19.org/blog/amazon-s3-zend-framework/) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8819466/1331671) for this topic.

All these approaches target to get a single file from S3.

**Coming from a `django` world I'd like to have a central place where I can set up S3 once and all my media files are automatically loaded instead of changing every line of code where I handle media files.**

Am I missing something obvious?

Is there a way to centralize it except writing a custom function and putting it in all the places I load media files?